# RAILS ActionMailer succeed but the MailAgent fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using this RAILS method to send out an email:

```
BrokerMailer.inform_carrier(...parameters...).deliver_now
```

I've tried what would happen when I send out email to recipients whos domain name is invalid. On the Linux server who runs the postfix daemon I see in the mail log:

```
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=irgendwaserfunden1010.de type=A: Host not found)
```

I have also checked the supported exception used by Net::SMTP but all these exceptions are not able to handle those deliver errors.

So what can I do, when the handover from the Rails ActionMailer to the MailServer works, but the MailServer can't send out because of wrong Domain Name ?

Comment: nslookup irgendwaserfunden1010.de results in ** server can't find irgendwaserfunden1010.de: NXDOMAIN This domain does not exist.  Or is it a local domain?

Comment: ** server can't find irgendwaserfunden1010.de: NXDOMAIN